# java- WinHandle not finding new window due to page refresh onclick

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently facing an issue when a new window is displayed in our current Web App.

Below is my current code I'm using to handle the new window.  When reviewing the logs, the ID of the original window is saving but not picking up the new window.

```
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='someXpath']")).click();
```

At this point a new window populates AND the original page reloads to a new location.  (2 total windows)

```
waitVar.waitforpagetoload(); // JS method to handle page being loaded.
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
} 
System.out.println("Pop up is: " +winHandle);
System.out.println("Parent window is: " +parentHandle);

driver.close(); 
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
```

When I print out the values I get the same string for both parent and new window.  I also have tried to run this through a for loop to print out each value in the driver.getWindowHandles and get an error as it only pulls one value (Parent window) for the array.  I believe the issue is the browser is reloading after the initial click.  Any suggestions on how to handle the new window being found with the original parent window refreshing after clicking? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not allowing enough time for the code to pick up.  Added an <del>Thread.sleep(3000)</del> explicit wait; and everything works as it should.  <del>While not the cleanest solution it does work as it should.</del>

Comment: Yuck... please change this to some sort of wait so that it's not Thread.sleep().

Comment: I have since removed the sleep and went with an explicit option.  Thanks :)